# JSPlumb Re-Create Connection after Connection detach

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I have divs which can be dragged and dropped on to a drawing area . These divs can be connected  manually using mouse drag and drop from source endpoint to the target endpoint .
      On clink over connections so created the connections get detached but the endpoints remain and the deleted connection can be recreated by the same manual process described above .
      Now I also save the drawing which is in the form of a flowchart of connected nodes in json format to disk file . On load of the file the flowchart is created perfectly showing all connections and nodes . Now I delete a connection on clicking over a node and it works . But now I cannot recreate the same connection again . The old node endpoints have become unresponsive .
     This is my load function : -

function  loadDrawing( jsPlumb , clientName , fileName )    {

```
var compositeObject = [ clientName.toString() , fileName.toString() ];

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: contextPath+"/file/load",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader( "Content-type", "application/json" );
    },
    // Send client and file name to the server
    data : JSON.stringify(compositeObject),
    async:false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response){
        var nodes = response.nodes;
        var endpoints = response.endpoints;
        var connections1 = response.connections;

        $.each(nodes, function( index, elem ) { 
              createElement( jsPlumb, elem.cssClass , elem.blockId , elem.nodetype , 
                    elem.dropStatus , elem.positionX, elem.positionY , elem.html, connections1["anchors"] );
        });

        var connections = response.connections;

        $.each(connections, function( index, elem ) {



             var connection1 = jsPlumb.connect({
              source: elem.pageSourceId,
              target: elem.pageTargetId,
              reattach: true,
              anchors: elem.anchors,

              endpoint:"Rectangle",
              maxConnections:-1, // Unlimited Connections .
              deleteEndpointsOnDetach:false,// Do not delete endpoints on connection removal.
              paintStyle:{ width:10 , height:10, strokeStyle:'#666' },
              isSource:true,
              connector: 'Flowchart' ,
              connectorStyle : { strokeStyle:"#666" },
              isTarget:true 
           });

        });

        // Reset global node counters 
        countLLC = response.counters[0].countLLC;
        countCCorp = response.counters[0].countCCorp;
        countSCorp = response.counters[0].countSCorp;
        countNonProfit = response.counters[0].countNonProfit;
        countSeries = response.counters[0].countSeries;
        countLivingTrust = response.counters[0].countLivingTrust;
        countLandTrust = response.counters[0].countLandTrust;
        countQRP = response.counters[0].countQRP;
        countLP = response.counters[0].countLP;

        wealthPlanningItemId = response.counters[0].countWPBNode;

        // Display detached captions
        for ( i=0 ; i<response.labelId.length ; i++)    {

            var detachedCaptionDiv =  $('<div>').attr('id',response.labelId[i].labelId)
                                            .html(response.labelContent[i].content);

            $('#nodeCaptionContainer1').append(detachedCaptionDiv);
        }
        alert("Image Open Successful .");
    }, 
    error: function(){      
        alert("Image Open Failure");
        } 
});
```

}

```
// Re-create nodes 
function createElement( jsPlumb , cssClass , nodeId , nodetype , dropStatus     , posX, posY , content, anchor1 )   {

var recreatedNode =  $('<div>').attr('id',nodeId).html( content );

recreatedNode.attr('title', nodetype );
recreatedNode.attr('dropstatus', dropStatus );
recreatedNode.attr('class', cssClass );

recreatedNode.css('position', 'absolute');
recreatedNode.css('left', posX+'px');
recreatedNode.css('top', posY+'px');



// Make nodes and their endpoints non-detachable
$(recreatedNode).removeClass("ui-draggable"); 
jsPlumb.draggable($(recreatedNode)); 




$("#content1").append(recreatedNode);
```

}

This is my connection deletion code : -

```
jsPlumb.bind('click', function (connection, e) {
     jsPlumb.detach(connection);
});
```

I have searched SOF , JSplumb Google groups , JSplumb API Docs , as well as most of the relevant links thrown up by google but could not find any help . Please help .

Comment: Does this have something to do with jQuery UI?

Comment: No it is not related with jQuery UI . The problem I am describing is purely a jsPlumb issue .

Comment: Then please don't use the tag. It wastes the time of people who follow `jquery-ui`

Answer (score 0):

Hi friends ,
                       after some research I have been able to find out my mistake actually it was something I did not know . I was trying to draw a connection between two nodes which didnot have the endpoints attached with a call to the jsPlumb.addEndpoint() . When you donot attach endpoints using this function it is not possible to set UUIDs to the endpoints and therefore it is not possible to connect these nodes from their pre-existing endpints which have been previously attached . 
         Hence moral of the story is that you need to attach endpoints to the nodes at the particular position then set UUIDs to them and then using the uuids to connect the nodes , otherwise it does not work . 
         See the API Docs to know more about the jsPlumb.addEndpoint() and jsPlumb.connect({ uuids:[ep_1.getUuid(),ep_2.getUuid()] }) functions . These are the once which I think are the most important .
         Hope this helps all those who are facing the same problem .